# Umderstanding the output of resizefs -d 32

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-image, resize2fs

After shrinking an ext4 file system with `resize2fs M` I mounted it to realize it has only 57% used. So I ran

```
$ resize2fs -d 32 -M rootfs-2021-06-28.img
resize2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
fs has 9698 inodes, 1 groups required.
fs requires 115683 data blocks.
With 1 group(s), we have 16352 blocks available.
Added 4 extra group(s), blks_needed 115683, data_blocks 147424, last_start 30686
Last group's overhead is 16416
Need 84997 data blocks in last group
Final size of last group is 101413
Estimated blocks needed: 232485
The filesystem is already 232485 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

I guess that 115683 data blocks plus 16416 overhead make the 57% of 232485, but I fail to add up those numbers to 232485 blocks. Honestly, I don't understand that calculation. The man page admits

> KNOWN BUGS
>
> The  minimum size of the filesystem as estimated by resize2fs may be incorrect, especially for filesystems with 1k
> and 2k blocksizes.

But I have 4k block size.

If `resize2fs` is the wrong tool for small numbers of blocks, please recomment a different approach to shrink the file system.

Answer (score 1):

As explained here the overhead margin used is big:

- [How to shrink a partition below the minimum size reported by resize2fs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/456723/140633)

Also se the linked c-code for detail.

To visualize it a bit more I did a little test using a 1G image file, filled it with less and less data in *one file* and used `resize2fs -M` on it:

From data file being 900M down to 600M estimated size is *above* the size of the partition.

- 900M: Estimated blocks needed: 440607 (1.68G)
- 800M: Estimated blocks needed: 382239 (1.46G)
- 700M: Estimated blocks needed: 323871 (1.24G)
- 600M: Estimated blocks needed: 298271 (1.14G)

At 500M and below

- 500M: Estimated blocks needed: 239903 (937M)
- 400M: Estimated blocks needed: 181534 (709M)
- 300M: Estimated blocks needed: 123166 (481M)
- 200M: Estimated blocks needed:  64798 (253M)
- 100M: Estimated blocks needed:  39198 (153M)

Tools like `gparted` etc. uses `resize2fs` under the hood. To make a partition that is *filled* one way could be to create a new image file of desired size and move the data there. One would of course need space to work with.

Else play around with the `-f` (force) flag and use:

```
resize2fs -d 32 -f file.img NEW_BLOCK_COUNT
```

> ```
> -f  Forces resize2fs to proceed with the filesystem resize operation,
>     overriding some safety checks which resize2fs normally enforces.
> ```

Comment: Thank you. I've seen that linked Q&A before, but it doesn't explain the output of `resize2fs -d 32`, at least not in a way I understand. You answer doesn't either. Anyhow, your experiment is interesting. The bottom line seems to be: `resize2fs` is a coward and during summer I'll try to find the time to add a »brave mode«. There is no risk with disk images.

Comment: @Philippos If you can include `dumpe2fs -h file.img` in question, it would likely be easier to expand on explanation.

Comment: Also added a comment on the `-f` flag.